# Using Keytool to extract MD5 signature from Android apk

Tags: java, android, md5, keytool

I have the RSA file but I didn't understand how to issue a command line like this:

```
keytool -printcert -file CERT.RSA
```

I mean, where do I write this line? I tried opening Keytool.exe but it opens and closes immediately.

Sorry for being so dumb.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Command Prompt and type it in there. Go to Start -> Run, type `cmd.exe` and hit enter. A command prompt will open up where you can use the `keytool` command. If it complains about not being able to find `keytool`, you need to change your working directory so it can find it. Use `cd C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin`, or another directory where `keytool.exe` can be found.

This tutorial might help understand the command prompt better:

http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr05/cos126/cmd-prompt.html